# Number of Subnets and total hosts

Tags: subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

Can someone please tell me what does this term means "A Class C network with 10 subnets"
What exactly is 10 subnets? I know a subnet is something like 255.255.255.0 and in case of class C network it can host 254 computers. Is my calculation true?

So if we have 10 subnets it means we can have 2540 computers in the network?

Comment: You admins at serverfault are extreme...hope not to see you on StackOverflow

Comment: Sean87 - notice that none of the people that voted to close were admins (or more properly, moderators). Questions like yours get asked **all the time** here, which is why we have a single comprehensive, well-answered canonical question on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

"A Class C network with 10 subnets" on it's own means nothing. I assume this a question being asked of you perhaps? Like, "split this class C network into 10 subnets?".

A subnet, is a sub-network of a classful network range (the clue is in the name). First you need to read about classful address ranges and learn a bit of basic binary math, then you can learn how to divide classful network ranges up into small subnets, to preserve addresses.

There are three major classes you need to know about, A, B and C; see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network

Then will be able to understand that blocks of IP addresses can be split into sub nets using simple binary math:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork